# azure.storage.blob._shared.authentication.AzureSigningError: Incorrect padding - Argo workflow

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-aks, argo-workflows

I'm getting Incorrect padding error while configuring a argo workflow to run a python function from my flask application to update the users group list everyday. Attached error logs and configuration details for the reference.

```
Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_shared/authentication.py", line 129, in _add_authorization_header
    signature = sign_string(self.account_key, string_to_sign)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_shared/__init__.py", line 45, in sign_string
    key = decode_base64_to_bytes(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_shared/__init__.py", line 35, in decode_base64_to_bytes
    return base64.b64decode(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/base64.py", line 87, in b64decode
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
binascii.Error: Incorrect padding

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/***/aad.py", line 76, in aad_groups
    aad_groups = cr_blob.read_blob('***', storage_key, 'aad', 'aad_groups.csv')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/***/data/blob.py", line 86, in read_blob
    blob_data = pd.read_csv(blob.download_blob())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/core/tracing/decorator.py", line 78, in wrapper_use_tracer
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_blob_client.py", line 914, in download_blob
    return StorageStreamDownloader(**options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_download.py", line 366, in __init__
    self._response = self._initial_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_download.py", line 466, in _initial_request
    process_storage_error(error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_shared/response_handlers.py", line 97, in process_storage_error
    raise storage_error
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_download.py", line 418, in _initial_request
    location_mode, response = self._clients.blob.download(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/core/tracing/decorator.py", line 78, in wrapper_use_tracer
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_generated/operations/_blob_operations.py", line 1592, in download
    pipeline_response = self._client._pipeline.run(  # type: ignore # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 211, in run
    return first_node.send(pipeline_request)  # type: ignore
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 71, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 71, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 71, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  [Previous line repeated 2 more times]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/policies/_redirect.py", line 158, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 71, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_shared/policies.py", line 546, in send
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_shared/policies.py", line 520, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 71, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 71, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 69, in send
    _await_result(self._policy.on_request, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_tools.py", line 34, in await_result
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_shared/authentication.py", line 152, in on_request
    self._add_authorization_header(request, string_to_sign)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_shared/authentication.py", line 135, in _add_authorization_header
    raise _wrap_exception(ex, AzureSigningError)
azure.storage.blob._shared.authentication.AzureSigningError: Incorrect padding
time="2023-07-24T08:59:03.472Z" level=info msg="sub-process exited" argo=true error="<nil>"
Error: exit status 1
```

And here is my `argo_workflow` config:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow                  
metadata:
  name: argo-aad
spec:
  entrypoint: aad-groups          
  templates:
    - name: aad-groups             
      container:
        image: ***.azurecr.io/image:latest
        env:
         - name: sql_db_key
           valueFrom:
             secretKeyRef:
               name: sqldbkey
               key: key
         - name: storage_key
           valueFrom:
             secretKeyRef:
               name: storagekey
               key: key
         - name: client_secret
           valueFrom:
             secretKeyRef:
               name: clientsecret
               key: key
         - name: client_id
           valueFrom:
             secretKeyRef:
               name: clientid
               key: key
         - name: directory_tenant_id
           valueFrom:
             secretKeyRef:
               name: directorytenantid
               key: key
        command: ["python", "-c"]
        args: ["import ***.aad as gaad; gaad.aad_groups('sql_db_key', 'storage_key', 'client_secret', 'client_id', 'directory_tenant_id')"]
```

I have created all the secrets for the parameters using below command and passing the values.

`kubectl create secret generic storagekey --from-literal=key=****************************************==`

Any advise please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> binascii.Error: Incorrect padding

"Incorrect padding" usually points to a data corruption or decryption issue that occurs during the process of decoding a base64-encoded string. It occurs when the credentials (like account key or SAS token) you're using for authentication are incorrect or corrupted.

- You are passing the secret keys directly as strings instead of referencing the values of the secrets. You should reference the secret values instead.

```yaml
args: ["import ***.aad as gaad; gaad.aad_groups(
    '{{inputs.parameters.sql_db_key}}', 
    '{{inputs.parameters.storage_key}}', 
    '{{inputs.parameters.client_secret}}', 
    '{{inputs.parameters.client_id}}', 
    '{{inputs.parameters.directory_tenant_id}}'
)"]
```

Also, pass the string `'sql_db_key'` as an argument. Instead, you should pass the actual value of the secret, as the variable name is being used.

- When creating secrets using `kubectl create secret generic`, check that the value you are passing for the key is base64-encoded.

**`echo -n "your-secret-value" | base64`**

- Replace the `args` field in the workflow template to pass the values of the secrets directly to the Python script, instead of passing the secret names.

**Args field:**

```
args: ["import ***.aad as gaad; gaad.aad_groups('{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}')".format(sql_db_key, storage_key, client_secret, client_id, directory_tenant_id)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the update. I just fixed this. As you advised I have stored all my secrets in azure key vault and passed them using CSI volume mounts.